# How can we get selected columns list form spring data jpa?

Tags: jpa, spring-data, entity

I am very new in JPA. I am trying to get the data from database with the selected columns like

> select firstName, lastName form userInfo
>
> select firstName, lastNameform userInfo where id = 1

with the help of siring data project.

currently I am using tow entity for same table like.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
Class User{
         @Column(name = "id", unique=true, nullable=false)
         int id;
         @Column(name = "name", nullable=false)
         String name;
         @Column(name = "address", nullable=false)
         Address address;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
Class UserLite{
         @Column(name = "id", unique=true, nullable=false)
         int id;
         @Column(name = "name", nullable=false)
         String name;
}
```

like a two different view but I am not sure, is there other methods for such kind of scenario.

Comment: You can define a projection: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

Comment: @AlanHay thanks for you reply, but i have one doubt. shall I use two entity as I mention above, is it a good practice?